# How to get only the numbers from a string which has got commas and hyphens in between

Tags: python

Consider like I have a string:

```
stringA = "values-are-10-1,20-2,30-1,40-4,50-3"
```

I need to get only the strings : desired output:

```
for stringA: 10-1,20-2,30-1,40-4,50-3
```

How to build regex for this.

Comment: You want to cut off the string "values-are-" from the beginning? Is that the requirement? because you don't need a regular expression for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use regex module:

```py
import re
stringA = "values-are-10-1,20-2,30-1,40-4,50-3"
re.sub("[^0-9\-\,]", "", stringA).strip("-")
```

##### Output

```
10-1,20-2,30-1,40-4,50-3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to do what you want :

```
(.[0-9]-[0-9])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtGnke/1)

With python code, you can do like this :

```
import re

regex = r"(.[0-9]-[0-9])"

stringA = "\"values-are-10-1,20-2,30-1,40-4,50-3\""

print([x.group() for x in re.finditer(regex, stringA, re.MULTILINE)])
```

**Output :**

```
['10-1', '20-2', '30-1', '40-4', '50-3']
```

Comment: `[0-9]+-[0-9]+` would make more sense, so you're not assuming the length of each number. I understand the OP's requirements are not very precise.

Comment: Yes, we can use also your suggestion